# In jqGrid do I have to manually call saveRow to trigger an ajax save request?

Tags: jqgrid

The documentation here is not very clear:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing&s[]=editurl#saverow

Do I have to manually make a `saveRow` call after the user finishes editing a table cell/row, or will jqGrid automatically trigger saveRow when the row (cell?) loses focus?

I'm giving jqGrid a `editurl` value in the initial setup, but I don't see any ajax requests going out when I finish editing a row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You use [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) with the parameter `keys: true`. In the case the method [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) will be called if the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the method [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#restorerow) will be called if the user press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. In the case you don't need to call [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) explicitly. Inside of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#events) one calls typically [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#restorerow) see here an example.
2. You can call [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) instead of [restoreRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#restorerow) in the [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#events) callback. Additionally (or alternatively) you can gives the user an interface to save current editing row. It can be some kind of "Save" button.

Comment: Hi @Oleg ,
From the answer above I need the second option, along with the save button and cancel button and the end of each row. Can you please point to me an existing project with asp.net web forms. I tried to go through what is existing but am unable to understand it correctly. It would be much help and appreciated if I could get a  small sample with guidelines for the following scenario:-
**1. Inline edit on onclick,
2. Save or or cancel button at the end of every row which have accessible events. So that I can make a ajaxcall on lick of save.**

Comment: @Ganesh: Sorry, but you ask too common questions. I have no Web Forms projects. Probably [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10871428/315935) is what one can use. Web Forms is very old and practically dead, so it's difficult to speak about *existing* ASP.NET WebForms projects. To add editing buttons in every row one can use `formatter: "actions"` for example. In case of usage [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you can just add the last column with some `name` property and `template: "actions"`. To save modifications to the server you need still wrote some server code.

Answer (score 0):

Although that's an old question, I'd like to add an example of explicitly calling `editRow` and then `saveRow`, which is a pretty frequent case.

The following code allows the user to just move freely between selected rows, and save the previous selected, edited row:

```
var grid = $('#gridName').jqGrid({
   // ... some grid properties ...
   editurl: 'clientArray',
   cellEdit: false, // that's the default, but just to make clear that wer'e in inline edit mode
   onSelectRow: utils.onSelectRow
   // ... some more grid properties ...
});
var utils = {
   prevRowId: null, // we have to keep the previous row id
   onSelectRow: function (rowId, selectionStatus, event) {
      if (rowId && rowId !== utils.prevRowId) {
         var $grid = $(event.target).closest('table');
         $grid.jqGrid('saveRow', utils.prevRowId);
         $grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowId, { keys: true });
         utils.prevRowId = rowId;
      }
   },
};
```

I couldn't find one of Oleg's official examples doing exactly this (they're all using buttons, [as this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SaveRow.htm), or calling `retrieveRow` instead of `saveRow`, [as this one](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_on_click/index.html)).